# Confusion on dimensioning power supply and fuse for a motor

Tags: power-supply, dimensions

I have the servo-motor model called MAC140. Here is a long manual including all other types of motors of the same company:
http://www.jvl.dk/files/pdf-1/user%20manuals/lb0047gb.pdf

If I go to section 5.1 of this manual, there is a section about the ratings of the motor models including MAC140. Here I uploaded it below for simplicity(Just left-click on it to make it bigger):
[image]

First of all, this motor has a rated power 134W. And as you can see, under the current consumption section there are two currents mentioned: average current consumption and peak supply current.

And in case of MAC140, what I understand is: when using a 24VDC supply the nominal rpm is 2000 and nominal current is 6A(Here also explains: http://www.jvl.dk/default.asp?Action=Details&Item=579). And there is also 16A peak current mentioned. I encircled this part with red.

But unlike the previous info, here the same motor is rated 160W and 6.3A http://www.jvl.dk/default.asp?Action=Details&Item=579

I want to use 24VDC and confused about the suitable power supply current. Do I need a power supply which can provide 6A or 16A? And what fuse should I use?

edit: And I guess if I connect lets say 3 motors to the same supply, I need a 24VDC supply with would have 3 times more current?

Comment: How much current you need is determined solely by how much torque you need. Do you know your torque requirements yet? The torque constant, Kt, for that motor appears to be 0.05625 Newton-meters per amp (about 8 oz-in per amp). Determine your torque requirements, and then you will know your current requirements.

Comment: Motor rule of thumb: Your maximum torque requirements determine your current, Your maximum speed requirements determine your voltage.

Comment: I dont know because it will not be for only one type of application, so I want to supply it with its naminal rated readings. If you read my question they give ratings as 134W and 160W for the same motor. And the nominal current is around 6A i guess. But peak is 16A.

Comment: On their site, the recomended PSU is 10A.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič you mean for a single motor?? where is the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link:http://www.jvl.dk/default.asp?Action=Details&Item=579 says you need 10A for single drive. 
If you have 3 motors, then it depends if they are spinning all of them at the same time or they interleave. The peak current will come into a play when accelerating, while in deceleration phase you get the regenerative power back. Therefore the most suitable PSU would have a large capacitor at the output. Some SMPSs have specified max capacitance they can handle, for countinous duty 6A is enough but you need a margin for peak load. 
For 3 drives you can use  something like 30A. You can DIY a PSU with a transformer, diode rectifier and large electolytic cap, you would need also inrush current limiter device at turn on. Or buy a SMPS with such overload characteristics that can accept large cap at the output, therefore you add a large elec. cap at the output (let say minimum 10 mili farad).
The fuses are nominal current, manual says 10Afor each drive.

EDIT: if you read the manual is writen everything:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think fuse is 10A for MAC140. Isnt it? I have a question here. I have the interface n MAC00-B4 for this motor. It is at page 118 Section here: 4.2  http://www.jvl.dk/files/pdf-1/user%20manuals/lb0047gb.pdf What I understand is this expansion module has already 10A fuse so I dont need anyother I guess. But I cannot figure out if this module also includes 4700uF cap. Do you think I need that cap at the output of the power supply? Another thing is they recommend a power supply with 10A for this motor, but the peak can go up to 16A. Is that because peak doesnt represent the rms current?

Comment: Sure, the cap is for supplying peak current and to receive peak regenerative current, 5mF/50V is pretty big and can't stay in that small can. It seems that you have solved the dillema about fuse, since it is built in. The only thing you need is a cap. bank like this: http://uk.farnell.com/epcos/b41560a7159m000/cap-alu-elec-15000uf-40v-screw/dp/1839337

Comment: Okay thanks.. But maybe you might edit your answer. You started by writing the model MAC140 requires 10A but you ended up using 6.3A in your calculations.

Comment: Just last thing. In this power-supply: http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0a59/0900766b80a59780.pdf There is "Output capacitance 7 000μF included inside the power supply" Would I still need an extra cap in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Peaks depend on drive performance, mainly parameters. The rated power is on rated RPM. Peaks may be during acceleration, and they are typically very short in terms of power consumption, but quite long for a power supply- like even 500msec or so.

But here are the good news: those peaks appear when the voltage on the motor is very low, so the power during the peaks is low too.

So you just should take like 25% power margin and relax.

Comment: what current for 24VDC would you recommend? 6A?

Comment: Take 8A. What are you buying, open frame or something serious?

Comment: I didnt buy yet. But rated current is 6A, do I really need 8A?

Comment: Ok, here how it goes. The motor will run OK. To know for sure about the power you must know exact system parameters- like inertia, acceleration, velocity, etc. Then you should know the efficiency. But i guess your best would be to guess. If so, take a little bigger. Or, if your estimation is that you actually will never get close to full power, you may even take 1A. It's all physics. If you run slowly and don't accelerate quickly, you don't need much power.

Comment: By the way, this coin has a flip side. Are you sure that 125W is enough? Maybe you need more? How do you actually know?

Comment: I wont exceed rated power

Comment: Then take power supply with 25% margin. 20% or 30% would work the same.

Comment: What do you mesn by %25 margin??

Comment: Rated power times 1.25. Just in case